# How do load content and meta data from a specific ID outside the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

Here is my code I'm using. I tried a few thing but neither of them worked. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$id = 29; 
$post = get_post($id); 
$title = apply_filters('get_the_title', $post->post_title);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
$meta = get_post_meta($id, 'example_meta', true);
echo "<h4 class='col-12'>", $title, "</h4>";                
echo "<h2 class='col-12 col-md-11 col-lg-8 py-5'>", get_the_subtitle($post), "</h2>";
echo $content;
echo $meta;
?>
```

Comment: what's the problem, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am not sure "get_the_subtitle" is the core function in WorPress. unless you have created one.

Comment: @FazleElahee You are right. I'am using a plugin for that. It's called "WP Subtitle" https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-subtitle/

Comment: @madalinivascu In the end I need have different div's that i can style them differently each time I'm using them.

Comment: @neongrain what do you mean by that?, you need each post to have a different style based on a meta value?

Comment: @madalinivascu yes, each post has to be styled differently and has to have a different html layout to archive that. to get you a idea of the concept: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybyn17mn6e1wh81/landing-1.png?dl=0 does that make sense for you? so thought I'll use a meta box for the blue text. so I can style it accordingly each time.

Comment: the page you have send in not a page who lists posts but a front page, the content on that page is usually static,to have multiple layout styles for each post you will need to create each layout individually and include that layout based on the meta value

Comment: @madalinivascu my intent is to do it manually to list each post by id and rearrange the html each time if needed. but I need the content to be editable for the editor of the page.

Comment: have you tried visualcomposer?

Comment: @madalinivascu i did not. But I don't wanna bloat the website with unnecessary plugins.

Comment: had the wrong ID. thanks a lot for your help. I tried for hours. my solution does already work. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can setup the post data with your desired post and then reset the post data.

```
<?php
$id = 29; 
$post = get_post($id); 
setup_postdata($post);
$title = apply_filters('get_the_title', $post->post_title);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
$meta = get_post_meta($id, 'example_meta', true);
echo "<h4 class='col-12'>", $title, "</h4>";                
echo "<h2 class='col-12 col-md-11 col-lg-8 py-5'>", get_the_subtitle($post), "</h2>";
echo $content;
echo $meta;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. Sadly it did not work for me. any alternatives?

Comment: Also try adding "global $post;" before $id = 29;

Comment: Thanks again. Sadly it did not work either. Do I use the get_post_meta correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is used correctly. I don't really see what the issue could be.

Comment: @sticksu Thanks for checking. Me neither. I will let you know when I found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have not test this code, i believe this will work.

```
    $id = 29;
$post = get_post($id);

if($post) {
    $title = get_the_title($post->ID);
    $content = do_shortcode( $post->post_content );
    $meta = get_post_meta($id, 'example_meta', true); // to make sure meta_key already exists for this posts.
    echo "<h4 class='col-12'>", $title, "</h4>";
    echo "<h2 class='col-12 col-md-11 col-lg-8 py-5'>", get_the_subtitle($post), "</h2>";
    echo $content;
    echo $meta;
}
```

Comment: This one did not work either. I checked the meta_key it is not correct one but i replaced it.